# How to close the current dialog in other class - Android

Tags: android, dialog

I have a custom dialog, from which I launch a BackgroundWorker Async Task and I want to close the current dialog in the post execute of the BackgroundWorker but I don't know how to get the current dialog because I created it in another class.

Thanks a lot.

Comment: you can call method of dismiss in that class

Comment: Make sure to dismiss dialog before closing activity or else you will face `android.view.WindowLeaked` exception.

Comment: dimiss() would be enough from onPostExecute

Comment: How can I dismiss() the dialog if I don't have the reference of my dialog ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to access your dialog (DialogFragment extended I guess) you have many approaches:

a) Make your BackgroundWorkerAsyncTask an inner class from your DialogFragment, being able to access your parent's attributes.

b) If you need it in other classes (that's why I think you made it an external class) you could have your own inner AsyncTask class inside your DialogFragment, and extends it from your BackgroundWorkerAsyncTask.

c) Pass in the constructor from your BackgroundWorkerAsyncTask the dialog you want to manage and in your postExecute dismiss it.

etc.

Choose whatever fits your needs.

Answer (score 2):

you can do this by various ways.

1. pass the dialog object in asynctask constructor and use this reference to dismiss it.
2. pass the class reference and with that refernce call a method of that class and that method contains dialog dismiss code

Answer (score 0):

Simply use:

```
alertDialogue.dismiss();
```

Comment: But how to link alertDialogue with my current open custom dialog ?

Comment: Don't need I solve the problem with another solution, I just passed the constructor of my Dialog in my BackgroundWorker. Thanks

Comment: That's awsm dude..Keep it up.